# How do I make a randomForest model size smaller?

Tags: r, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, random-forest

I've been training randomForest models in R on 7 million rows of data (41 features). Here's an example call:

myModel <- randomForest(RESPONSE~., data=mydata, ntree=50, maxnodes=30)

I thought surely with only 50 trees and 30 terminal nodes that the memory footprint of "myModel" would be small. But it's 65 megs in a dump file. The object seems to be holding all sorts of predicted, actual, and vote data from the training process.

What if I just want the forest and that's it? I want a tiny dump file that I can load later to make predictions off of quickly. I feel like the forest by itself shouldn't be all that large...

Anyone know how to strip this sucker down to just something I can make predictions off of going forward?

Comment: `?randomForest` advises against using the formula interface with large numbers of variables... are the results any different if you don't use the formula interface?  The *Value* section of `?randomForest` also tells you how to turn off some of the output (importance matrix, the entire forest, proximity matrix, etc.).

Comment: May have just answered my own question...nulling out the fields I don't want in the model seems to be sufficient. If I just do: myModel$votes <- NULL myModel$predicted <- NULL myModel$oob.times <- NULL myModel$y <- NULL the model shrinks to 13k and is still evaluatable. Anyone see a problem with this?

Comment: If you turn you votes object to NULL you will not be able to make a prediction.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of rF - it always keeps as you said -> predicted, actual, and vote data - and there is assumption that the bigger data you train rF the bigger model would be; one solution is to cluster your rows / do feature selection on your cols (inptus) to make your matrix smaller;

Comment: @John, why don't you post a small example showing that you can NULL out those components and still make predictions?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to get out of the habit of posting answers as comments...

`?randomForest` advises against using the formula interface with large numbers of variables... are the results any different if you don't use the formula interface?  The *Value* section of `?randomForest` also tells you how to turn off some of the output (importance matrix, the entire forest, proximity matrix, etc.).

For example:

```
myModel <- randomForest(mydata[,!grepl("RESPONSE",names(mydata))],
  mydata$RESPONSE, ntree=50, maxnodes=30, importance=FALSE,
  localImp=FALSE, keep.forest=FALSE, proximity=FALSE, keep.inbag=FALSE)
```

Comment: None of the items that appear to be toggleable help.
If I just do:
myModel$votes <- NULL
myModel$predicted <- NULL
myModel$oob.times <- NULL
myModel$y <- NULL

the model shrinks to 13k and is still evaluatable. Anyone see a problem with this?

Comment: It doesn't seem like `keep.forest=FALSE` would be a good idea if you want to make predictions with the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `tuneRF` function in R to know the number of trees and make the size smaller.

```
tuneRF(data_train, data_train$Response, stepFactor = 1.2, improve = 0.01, plot = T, trace = T)
```

use `?tuneRF` to know more about inside variables.